# Mask Image with disappearing text

Tags: css, image, background, mask, sticky

I want to have a background and a mask which lie on top of each other. So the visitor has an impression of an normal background image. But when the visitor scrolls down the text/navbar is sticky and floats behind the image (in relation to the movement). I have seen an similiar effect on this Website http://aganaplocha.com/netmag/mountains/ but it doesn't work on mine https://www.bemase.com/gallery(1).

I am happy for generally or specific tips/solutions.
I am new into coding and just doing it since a few weeks, so maybe the solution ain't that difficult.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask], and update your post with a [mre]. Questions must contain the code you're having trouble with. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

Set the `z-index` of the text to `-9` and the `position` to `fixed`.